# phpmailer taking 5 seconds.. yet php mail() taking less than 1

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send out mass emails and I am using phpmailer  class to send the emails and they are taking 5.2 seconds each to send!! Here is my code, any idea why its taking so long?

```
<?php

//============

        require '../includes/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $time_start = microtime(true);


//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('support@site.com', 'site');
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('support@site.com', 'site');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('email@gmail.com', 'Name');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'subject ';
$mail->msgHTML('test');
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}





            $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo "Process Time 3: {$time} <br/>";
    // Process Time: 1.0000340938568



?>
```

Comment: Currently your time includes also time of initialization of the `$mail` and so on. Try to take initial time before `send`. Also `phpmailer` generates all headers and makes checkups. Did you check the load of your server?

Comment: i have tried putting $time_start = microtime(true); before the if statement and it still says 5 seconds. What do you mean check the load of the server?

Comment: i am using google apps for business.. i just used the functions to connect to my gmail account to pass the mail and now it takes 2 seconds... i think google apps for business may be interfering or something? :S

Comment: Right now phpmailer is not using SMTP connection. All delays might have place due to the high server or smtp mail server load. `phpmailer` typically works fast, not so fast as `mail`, but not 5 seconds either.

Comment: Why do you say it takes 5 sec, then show it taking 1? Even 1 sec is very slow - I have no trouble sending over 50 messages per second with PHPMailer, even with remote SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

To get a more accurate picture of what's going on, use a profiler - it will make it immediately obvious where the time is going. I recommend xdebug with qcachegrind, or PHPStorm.

You'll often find that SMTP to localhost is faster than you expect - when you call sendmail with postfix, the sendmail binary makes an SMTP connection to localhost anyway, so you can reduce overhead by using SMTP directly. See the postfix docs for more on that.

`msgHTML()` does various things you may not need - setting `Body` and `AltBody` directly will be faster.

As others have mentioned, if you want to send quantity, much of the overhead can (and should) be moved outside the sending loop, and you can gain from things like keepalive.

Make sure you're using the latest PHPMailer - there were some fairly big speedups in recent versions, especially in SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
```

change it to:

```
$mail->IsMail();  // set mailer to use Mail
```